# Avoid exception when writing to null file

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter, filedialog

I'm doing some WPF exercises and I could succesfully write a file with content on it.

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Text file (*.txt)|*.txt";
sfd.ShowDialog();
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(sfd.FileName))
{
  sw.Write(container.Text);
  sw.Close();
}
MessageBox.Show("File " + sfd.FileName + " created at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
container.ResetText();
```

That `using (StreamWriter)` is rising the exception.

If I try to save a file, but, close the window before informing a file name , things go bad.

How can I avoid that ? I tried checking if the file is null ( both above and inside the `using` statement but it still goes off.

Comment: Please define `things go bad`.

Comment: Read the documentation for SaveFileDialog.FileName.  It will be an empty string, not null, if no file is selected: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the result of ShowDialog:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Text file (*.txt)|*.txt";
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, container.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("File " + sfd.FileName + " created at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    container.ResetText();
}
```

Comment: it says the operator ?? can't be applied to the operands. =/

Comment: Are you using a WPF SaveFileDialog (Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog) or a WinForms SaveFileDialog (System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog)? If you're developing a WPF application, you should be using the WPF one, which returns a Nullable<bool>, which the ?? operator works with.

Comment: Your question implies you're using WPF (although I see now that you've tagged the question with WinForms -- this is confusing). I'll update with my answer with the WinForms solution.

Comment: Also, consider using `File.WriteAllText` instead of a `StreamWriter`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @MichaelGunter ! Thanks for helping.

Comment: Could u tell me why using `File.WriteAllText` over `StreamWriter` ?

Comment: Because it yields a cleaner solution with less code. I'll update my answer to show you.